# Lists in Python becoming very complex

Tags: python

I have a simple function which takes a 2D list as a parameter:

```
def get_noise_estimate(imag_array):
    temp = []

    temp.append(imag_array[:20])
    temp.append(imag_array[-20:])
```

In an example instance, it has 305 elements, each with 129 elements. I like to think of this has 305 columns each with 129 rows. I found out these things using my debugger:

```
>>> len(imag_array)
305

>>> len(imag_array[0])
129
```

When I get the first 20 and last 20 'columns' of the array and append it to `temp` I get the following:

```
>>> len(temp)
2
>>> len(temp[0])
20
>>> len(temp[1])
20
>>> len(temp[0][0])
129
```

My `temp` list has become quite confusing. I'd like `len(temp)` to equal 40 rather than 2 blocks of 20. To illustrate what I mean I'll show how I might do something similar in Java:

```
int[] temp = new int[40];

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    temp[i] = imag_array[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   temp[i+20] = imag_array[imag_array.length-i]
}
```

The above is off the top of my head but I hope it makes clear what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
temp.append(imag_array[:20])
temp.append(imag_array[-20:])
```

to

```
temp.extend(imag_array[:20])
temp.extend(imag_array[-20:])
```

The `append` command adds something as the last element of `temp`.  So it's making the first element of `temp` be the list `imag_array[:20]`.  `extend` takes all the elements of the list in the argument and adds each to the end of the list.

(and note Jay's answer: `temp = imag_array[:20]+imag_array[-20:]` is actually cleaner - it doesn't require predefining `temp` and avoids using `.append`)

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = imag_array[:20] + imag_array[-20:]
```